# Search for a string from 100 million rows of strings

Tags: database, algorithm

I have this text file containing some md5 hashes, 100 million rows of them. I have this another smaller file with few thousand md5 hashes. I want to find the corresponding indices of these md5 hashes from this new smaller file to the old bigger file.

what is the most efficient way to do it? Is it possible to do it in like 15 mins or so?

I have tried lots of things but they do not work. First I tried to import the bigger data to a database file and create an index on the md5 hash column. Creating this hash takes for ever. I am not even sure if this will increase the query speed much. Suggestions?

Comment: @user2864740 CREATE INDEX my_index ON table (sequence_hash) using HASH;?? This is taking like ages

Comment: That's fine, it will (the fact that the hashes aren't ordered hurts a good bit too; *sorting the input file first may help a good bit!*). However queries against it will be fast.

Comment: @user2864740. How long will it take to do one query. If it takes like a second, then it is still several hours. The index that I have created is it the right one? or I have to do something else. I just got that example from somewhere not sure if it is the appropriate one. sequence_hash is the one containing the md5 hash

Comment: my query would be just select id from table where sequence_hash='some_hash'

Comment: What kind of DB you tried to use? From your usecase, a key-value DB should work for you. Or you can try some lightweight mapreduce framework to do this if you need to do this often and the file changes often.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do this in db - use a simple program.**

1. Read the md5 hashes from the small file into a **hash map** in memory, that allow for fast look-ups.
2. Then read through the md5's in the big file one row at a time, and check if the row is in the **hash map**.

Average look-up time in the **hash map** ought to be close to **O(1)**, so **the process time of this is basically how fast you can read through the big file**.

The 15 minutes is easily obtained with today's hardware with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: 100 Megarows à 32 Bytes = ca. 3.2 GByte of data. Reading them in 15 Minutes translates to 3.5 Megabytes per second, which should easily be doable with modern hardware.

I recommend **not** to use a database, but process consisting of some easy steps:

1. Sort your data - you have to do this only once, and you can parallelize much of it
2. Read the small file into memory (sorted into an array)
3. Cycle this array:
4. Read the big file line by line, comparing with the current line of your array (first compar e first byte, then first and second, ...) until you either reach a match (output index) or pass the value (output "not found")
5. Move to next array element

The initial sort might easily take longer than 15 minutes, but the lookups should be quite fast: Ify you have enough RAM (and an OS that supports processes bigger than 2GB) you should be able to get a compare rate at least an order of magnitude faster!

Comment: There's practically no point in sorting the initial data: although it gets you O(1) compares while scanning the full complexity will be `N * log(N)` (sorting) + `N` (comparisons). On the other hand, a simple linear scan will take `N * (cost of looking for the pattern in the smaller set of patterns)`, which means `N * 1` with a hashmap, or `N * log(smaller number of patterns)` using binary search in the smaller set.

Comment: THe central point of the initial sort is to convert random IO into sequential IO, which can easily perform an order of magnitude better on today's hardware!

Comment: The IO doesn't need to be random; you can read the file sequentially and still solve the problem efficiently.

Comment: @Clément - If you want to compare with order guarantee, you either need to sort, or you need random IO. The algorithm you proposed in your answer relies on a complete compare (which doesn't need sort guarantees), absolutely ruining any CPU cache usage and creating tons of wrong branch predictions. You end up being memory bandwidth bound, which is much harder (and costlier) to scale than sequential IO bandwidth. Rabin-Karp for large comparison sets (=bigger than CPU cache) is out of date, since CPU performance and RAM bandwidth have started differing so wildly.

Comment: Hence the simplified, second part of my answer regarding using a set. In the end it's hard to say, but I really doubt that sorting the whole of the data would be faster than any of the other solutions here. I like @Ebbe M. Pedersen's answer's actually.

Comment: The point about sorting is, that you only need to do it once, and then profit for every lookup set - IIUC the OQ is about this use case.

Comment: That's not obvious from the OQ IMHO; I'd understand that it needs to be done only once; if it's to be repeated a lot of times, then yes, sorting would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

There are algorithms specifically designed for searching for multiple strings in a large file. One of them is Rabin-Karp. I have a [blog post about this](http://pit-claudel.fr/clement/blog/linear-time-probabilistic-pattern-matching-and-the-rabin-karp-algorithm/).

More simply, the following pseudo-code should get you there in no time :

```
Load your few thousand strings in a set data structure
For each line (index: i) in your file
    If that line appears in your set of values
        print i
```

This will be very fast: The set data structure will have almost-instant lookups, so the IO will the culprit, and 100 million hashsums will fit in 15 minutes without too much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

(1) every record in the small file appears in the large file

(2) the data in each file is randomly ordered.

Options:

(1) For each record in the large file, search the small file linearly for a match.  Since most searches will not find a match, the time will be close to
 Nlarge * Nsmall * k
where k represents the time to attempt one match.

(2) For each record in the small file, search the large file linearly for a match.  Since every search will find a match, the time will be about
 Nlarge/2 * Nsmall * k.

This looks twice as fast as option (1) -- but only if you can fit the large file completely into fast memory.  You would probably need 6 GB of RAM.

(3) Sort the small file into an easily searchable form.  A balanced binary tree is best, but a sorted array is almost as good.  Or you could trust the author of some convenient hash table object to have paid attention in CS school.  For each record in the large file, search the structured small file for a match.  The time will be
 log2 Nsmall * s
to sort the small file, where s represents the time to sort one record, plus
 log2 Nsmall * Nlarge * k
for the scan.  This gives a total time of
 log2 Nsmall * (s + Nlarge * k).

(4) Sort the large file into an easily searchable form.  For each record in the small file, search the structured large file for a match.  The time will be
 log2 Nlarge * s
to sort the large file plus
 log2 Nlarge * Nsmall * k
for the scan, giving a total of
 log2 Nlarge * (s + Nsmall * k).

Option (4) is obviously the fastest, as reducing any coefficient of Nlarge dominates all other improvements.  But if the sortable structure derived from the large file will not fit completely into RAM, then option (3) might turn out to be faster.

(5) Sort the large file into an easily searchable form.  Break this structure into pieces that will fit into your RAM.  For each such piece, load the piece into RAM, then for each record in the small file, search the currently loaded piece for a match.  The time will be
 log2 Nlarge * s
to sort the large file plus
 log2 Nlarge * Nsmall * k * p
for the scan, where the structure was broken into p pieces, giving a total of
 log2 Nlarge * (s + Nsmall * k * p).

With the values you indicated for Nlarge and Nsmall, and enough RAM so that p can be kept to a single digit, option (5) seems likely to be the fastest.

Comment: "Time to sort one record" does not really make sense, does it? Option 5 is much slower than option 3, because the s in option 3 is Nsmall, while the s in option 5 is Nlarge. Sorting takes N*log(N): your s depends on the sample size.

Comment: Option 5) Sorting 100 million records seems to be a really bad idea. Reading small file into hash map and then make one look-up in the hash map for each entry in the large file gives a run time of O(n). Can hardly be done any faster.

Comment: Option 3) Please explain why a balanced binary tree is better than a sorted array. My experience is that, for searching, a sorted array is better because it's simpler and gives better locality of reference.

Comment: Gentlemen you are correct; I have blundered.  I have mischaracterized the sort time as O(log2(N)) when it is actually O(N*log2(N)).  Option (3) is faster.  Option (5) is unnecessary.