# Searching a record from a file with efficient time complexity. File has 1 billion records. With key value pair

Tags: java, database, performance, architecture, hashmap

Recently I appeared for an interview for Java developer.

I was asked this question.

> If there is a file which has 1 billion lines each line is a record
> which consists of key-value pair.

```
For example : 

<name1>, <mobile_no1>
<name2>, <mobile_no2>
```

> Now if there is a record that is present somewhere in the middle of
> the file. How to find the row with minimum time complexity.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672404/search-for-a-string-from-100-million-rows-of-strings

Comment: Interview questions, like homework question, require that you show us your own solution and explain where you got stuck. Also, be aware that many times, interview questions are intended for you to explain your way of thinking and why you think there is or there is not a good solution.